# Как программно открыть google+ приложение?

Tags: java, android, google-plus

Здравствуйте. Cтолкнулся с проблемой программного открытия google+ из моего приложения. У меня есть приложение, которое отправляет посты в google+, а я хочу сделать чтоб по нажатию но кнопку открывалось само приложение google+. Вроде это делается через Intent. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: Это делается через `Intent filter`.

[action-send-and-google-app-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599923/action-send-and-google-app-in-android

Comment: Мне нужна не  передача данных в google+. А именно открытие стандартного приложения google+ с своего приложения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По запросу в [google](http://google.com) с текстом [android start another application](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20start%20another%20application&safe=off) первый же результат оказался правильным. (прозрачно намекаю на то, что можно было нагуглить ответ за 8 секунд)  
А конкретно там написано вот что(так и быть, "прожую даже за вас":

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Где `com.package.address` - **package id** запускаемого приложения.  
Дальше идем в [гугл плей](https://play.google.com/store), и находим там [Гугл +](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=google%2B)  
Далее переходим на [страницу самого приложения](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus), и смотрим в адресную строку, из которой успешно извлекаем **package id** (*com.google.android.apps.plus*)  
Ну, и на конец, заменяем **package id** в вышеприведенном коде на нужный нам, и получаем

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло